# Custom Date Range Controls Not Working in Looker Studio with BigQuery DataSource

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio, google-analytics-4

I'm experiencing an issue with Looker Studio when using a BigQuery datasource in relation to date range controls. Despite setting up everything correctly, the tables in my reports do not update when I adjust the date range using Looker Studio's controls. The data remains static and does not reflect the changes made to the date range.

**Here's what I've confirmed so far:**

My SQL queries in BigQuery are correct and return the expected results.

I have enabled the 'Enable date range' parameters within the Looker Studio connector settings.

I have attempted to filter the date within my BigQuery query to reflect the date range control.

Despite these checks, the date range controls in Looker Studio are not affecting the data displayed in my tables. The goal is for the data to be flexible and for tables to update according to the date range specified by the Looker Studio's date range control feature.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can provide insight into why the date range controls might not be influencing the data as expected? Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable date range' parameter is a trap, and it does not work as you think.
first of all, try to disable it(it is only helpful for fixed date ranges), then update your BigQuery query to include a date field without a specific time range. then in reports you can see a Date Range dimension field and you should add your query date field here. These actions should fix your issue, but if it still remains, you can check this medium article to troubleshoot it. https://medium.com/@aliiz/troubleshooting-date-range-filters-in-looker-studio-dashboards-with-bigquery-data-sources-0416a399425e